# avr-gcc: No symbols are located for any call stack frames

Tags: c, debugging, optimization, linker, avr-gcc

I am developed a GCC C Executable Project with Atmel Studio 6. The target device is ATtiny2313A. There are a C-file and other header files.

When I set the optimization for size I am not able to debug the solution because when I step into a function contained in a header file the debugger shows the error `No source available. No symbols are located for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed`.

The debugger works fine with all the other optimization types (`-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3`).

Furthermore the software works on the real chip.

I need to know the timing of my code but i need also to save flash memory space therefore i cannot avoid to debug the code with optimization size.

It seems the problem is about the linker that is not able to link the different parts of the code because some symbols are missed. 
How can I make it use all the necessary symbols?

Comment: Not sure if `-Os` will override it, but you can try adding `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` to your compilation flags.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have are using the gdwarf2 object file format.  I had a similar issue with the compiled code not linking back to the source code correctly.